# Object #<HTMLTableSectionElement> has no method 'append' in Backbone.js View self.el

Tags: backbone.js

```
Window.TableView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    initialize: function() {
    },
    tagName:"tbody",

    render: function() {  
      var self=this;
      console.log(self.el);//will log <tbody></tbody>self.el.append("<tr></tr>");

      return self.el;
    }
); 

tbView=new TableView();
tbView.render();
```

If I build a new view, and call the render function; I'll get the error Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'append' has no method 'append' ...Is there a way to get it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone [`view.el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) is a reference to the raw DOM object, which has no method `append`. In order to manipulate the element using jQuery, you should use the cached jQuery selector property [`view.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) instead:

```
self.$el.append("<tr></tr>");
```